# What was the size of the ancient Sphene-ship of the Radch Universe and how many ancillaries did she operate?

Tags: spaceship, imperial-radch, ann-leckie

What do you think, was it small, like Mercies and Swords, or large, like Justices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The author herself is not sure, but speculates that its size is intermediate between a Mercy and a Sword:

[image: Twitter Conversation with Ann Leckie]

Transcript:

> (Matt Gutting): @ann_leckie is there anywhere other than you I could go to answer this question? Don't have books with me. (9:48 AM - 7 Nov 2016)
>
> (Ann Leckie): @matgutting I actually don't know for sure! I didn't need it for the books. That said, probably larger than a Mercy smaller than a Sword.

Comment: Wow! Feeling like I was touched by the star. Thanks a lot.